# Error while trying to import

Tags: import, error

Got this error when trying to import my file as fbx, any ideas on how to fix it?[image]

Comment: I find it a common problem with blender 3.0 mostly.

Comment: im in 2.83, is it normal too?

Comment: Try importing in another format. Download with a different format and test it.

Comment: That's the sort of error that often means the FBX file is corrupted in some way.  You might want to try the file with other programs to see if it's OK.  Otherwise, it's possibly a bug in the exporter.